# Do these properties characterize number rings?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

Suppose $R$ is a Dedekind domain with the following properties:

- at every prime of $R$ the residue field is finite;
- fibers of the map $\text{Spec }R\to \text{Spec } \mathbb Z$ are finite.

Is $R$ isomorphic to [a subring of] the number ring of some number field?

Comment: What is the map between the spectrum rings?

Comment: @Adam probably the map induced by the omly map from the integers to the ring

Comment: $\text{Spec } R$ here means the set of prime ideals?

Comment: Yes to both things!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no.  E.g. take $R = \mathbb Z[1/2]$.  A different kind of counterexample is given by taking $R = \mathbb Z_p$.

You need an additional hypotheses.  Taking $R$ to be of finite type over $\mathbb Z$ will eliminate the second kind of counterexample, though not the first.  If you take $R$ to be finite over $\mathbb Z$, you do get a subring of a ring of integers.

Comment: Good point! In fact if one only asks that $R$ is a Dedekind domain finite over $\mathbb Z$ then the two conditions that I wrote are automatically satisfied, since a finite morphism has finite fibers and by Nullstellensatz for Jacobson rings $R/\mathfrak p$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ for $\mathfrak p\in \text{Spec } R$ and $p\mathbb Z=\mathfrak p\cap \mathbb Z$.